# Eclipse not opening, downloaded Eclipse ADT bundle

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a Windows 7, 64-bit operating system. I downloaded the Eclipse ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. I verified that I downloaded the 64 bit version and have downloaded the 64-bit version of the Java Development Kit. I unzipped the file and tried to run eclipse.exe but nothing happens, no error but eclipse doesnt open. I deleted and re-downlaoded the Eclipse ADT bundle hoping that it would fix the problem but no luck. Any one know any solutions?

Comment: Hi, try when you run the `eclipse.exe` , check your `task manager` processes if eclipse.exe is on the list, so you can check if its really running or your pc is just slow so it takes time to load the IDE.

Comment: try giving it a different workspace, maybe run it as admin, maybe you have a misconfigured Java with the JAVA_HOME pointing in the wrong direction

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, eclipse can't find the java binary in your computer, and it fails to launch.

You can check if java binary is correctly set just typing this in the command line:

```
java -version
```

If it doesn't show you any version number, that's it.

If you haven't restarted Windows since you installed the JDK, try restarting Windows so you are sure that Windows is aware of the new binary.

If that doesn't work, you can uninstall the JDK, restart, and install the JDK again.

Note: most of the application won't care about it, but sometimes JDK7 can give you problems. I'd recommend you installing JDK6. Anyway, that's entirely your choice.

Comment: just to add, eclipse SHOULD run on jdk 7 (the latest version at least, which is Luna) because that's the required jdk for building with Android L Developer preview.

Comment: yep. It should. But as of now, they are still recommending JDK6 on their download page... I'll stick with JDK6 in my main developer machine and load JDK7 in another one (a machine dedicated to Android L), just to be sure. Not that I don't trust them, but I don't trust them.

Comment: my eclipse.ini has been configured to use jre7 since i updated adt for the L Preview. no problems encountered so far, and i can develop for both L Preview and lower versions without issue. no need for different machines. though i'm suspecting OP has an entirely different problem than just jdk/jre versions.

Comment: In my case, most of my projects have always worked ok with JDK7. But there is a bunch of quite more complex apps that just don't work when compiled with JDK7. Most of the times, when there's some heavy usage of binaries compiled with NDK and JNI (of course). For "normal" apps, anyway, I agree with you in that JDK7 should work ok (it even makes eclipse run a bit faster and brings a couple of nice features).